# Java, Largest prime factor

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to solve this question:
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler003/submissions/code/2977447

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of a given number N?
>
> Input Format 
>   First line contains T, the number of test cases. This is followed by T lines each containing an integer N.
>
> Output Format 
>   For each test case, display the largest prime factor of N.
>
> Constraints
>
> ```
>      1≤T≤10 
>     10≤N≤1012
> ```

and my code below gets a timeout error for the fifth test (which we don't know about the actual content). any thought why did it fail the test? thanks

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

/* Author: Derek Zhu
 * 1and1get2@gmail.com
 * https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler003
 * */
// The part of the program involving reading from STDIN and writing to STDOUT has been provided by us.

public class Solution {
    public static boolean D = true;
    static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));
    static StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
            IOException {
        int numOfCases = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCases; i++){
            calculateCase(Long.parseLong(in.readLine())); 
        }


    }
    private static void calculateCase(Long input) throws IOException{

        if (D) System.out.println("Processing: " + input);
        long largestPF = prime(input);

        if (D) System.out.print("Final calculate: ");
        System.out.println(largestPF);
    }
    private static long prime(long n){
        long i = 2;
        while ( n % i != 0 && i < n){
            i ++;
        }
        if (D) System.out.println("found i: " + i);

        if (i < n){
            return prime(n/i);
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }
    public static int primeFactors(BigInteger number)     {
        BigInteger copyOfInput = number;
        int lastFactor = 0;
        for (int i = 2;
        BigInteger.valueOf(i)
        .compareTo(copyOfInput) <= 0; i++) {
            if (copyOfInput.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(i))
            .compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) 
            {
                lastFactor = i;
                copyOfInput = copyOfInput
                .divide(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
                i--;
            }
        }
        return lastFactor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `N` really limited to 1012, or did something get lost in the cut-and-paste process?

Comment: Is there a reason you're showing us the `primeFactors` method?  It doesn't appear to be used.

Comment: Some general suggestions: (1) Your loop doesn't have to go up to `i < n`; you can cut it off much sooner.  (2) You can skip most even divisors.  (3) If you find that 2 and 3 don't divide `prime`, but 5 does, then when you look for prime factors of `prime/5`, you shouldn't need to try 2 and 3 again.  I don't know if those suggestions are enough to pass.

Comment: @ajb sorry I should have checked, it should be 10^12.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ajb

as it turns out, taking another method would be much efficient.

```
private static long method2(long NUMBER){
        long result = 0;
        for(int i = 2; i < NUMBER; i++) {
            if(NUMBER % i == 0 && isPrime(NUMBER / i)) {
                result = NUMBER / i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
    private static boolean isPrime(long l) {
        for(long num = 2, max = l / 2 ; num < max; num++) {
            if(l % num == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

complete code with comparison of time can be found here:
https://github.com/1and1get2/hackerrank/blob/master/Contests/ProjectEuler%2B/003_LargestPrimeFactor/src/Solution.java

Comment: nope... still not working. found an interesting number: 222391364219

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (NUMBER<2){

    return -1; 
 }
 int result = 0;

 for (int i =2; NUMBER>i; i++ ){

    if (NUMBER%i==0){
        result = NUMBER / i;
        if (result/1==result && result/result==1 && result%2!=0 && result%3!=0 && result%5!=0 && result%7!=0){
             break;
        }
     }
 }
 return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.text.*;
 import java.math.*;
 import java.util.regex.*;

 public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    int count,k=0,n=0;
    long arr[]=new long[1000000];
    long arr1[]=new long[1000000];
    long arr2[]=new long[10000000];
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
         arr[a0] = in.nextLong();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        for(int j=2;j<=arr[i];j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]%j==0)
            {
              arr1[k]=j;  
              k++;
            }
        }
        for(int l=0;l<k;l++)
        {
            count=0;
           for(int m=1;m<=arr1[l];m++)
           {
               if(arr1[l]%m==0)
               {
                   count++;
               }
           } 
           if(count==2)
           {
             arr2[n]=arr1[l];
             n++;  
           }
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr2);
        System.out.println(arr2[arr2.length-1]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).